# How to fix "Named Pipes Provider error: 40" When trying to open connection?

Tags: c#, oracle, pipe, provider, named

I'm trying to make a button that inserts query into **Oracle Database**. But when I try to open connection error pops:

```
SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection(IssueTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
            sqlc.Open();
```

Breaks at `sqlc.Open();` with message:

`Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and I've installed ODAC.
I've gone through other people's questions, but they were not helpful. Its confusing for me because I can populate `DataGridView` and `comboBox` with data. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why does the error message refer to SQL Server if you think you're connecting to Oracle? What is your ConnectionString set to? Which driver are you using?

Comment: Its set to `IssueTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString` from `connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/XE;PASSWORD=123;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=BAZE"` Maybe the better question is, how do I access Oracle database or even how do I insert query into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it all wrong, [Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole) ring some bells for me.

To access Oracle Database you use `OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();`

As learned from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkAIiDWF0HE